# Strong Parameters claims param not found when it's present

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

So for some reason I'm getting the `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error. It says `incident` parameter is missing however it's **clearly** present:

```
Started PATCH "/incidents/16/assign-score" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-23 23:07:12 -0500
Processing by IncidentsController#update_override_score as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RSGaHrrTrO5DoX8dVEtVNQX8OJnRAD35YRSCAvZtNr4=", "incident"=>{"id"=>"16", "score_override"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Save legitimacy score", "id"=>"16"}
Unpermitted parameters: id, score_override
  Incident Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "incidents".* FROM "incidents" WHERE "incidents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "16"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "incidents".* FROM "incidents" WHERE "incidents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "16"]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 9ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: incident):
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:66:in `update_override_score'


  Rendered /Users/justinbull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/justinbull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/justinbull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/justinbull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (62.8ms)
```

Relevant controller code:

```
class IncidentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_incident, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :edit_override_score, :update_override_score]

  # ...

  def update_override_score
    override_params = params.require(:incident).permit(:score_override)
    override_params[:score_override] = nil if override_params[:score_override].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.update_attributes! score_override: override_params[:score_override]
        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit_override_score' }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_incident
      @incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Any idea how this could possibly happen? You can see the incident hash right in the Parameters line of the log.

Comment: Looks like you're using CanCan, yeah? There are known issues with CanCan and strong params -- see, eg, [this one](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835). [Here's](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815) a solution that worked for me that might be relevant to your problem.

Comment: @JoshLeitzel Well fancy that. It's CanCan. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Josh Leitzel, he pointed me in the right direction. I'm using the CanCan gem which is, at 1.6.10, has trouble with Rails 4. His comment explains the workaround.

I had to move the `param.require()` logic into a controller method `incident_params` however.